# when the .jar contains EventBus module

Tags: android, xamarin

I have to bind a (.jar) file which contains an `Eventbus` module. When I call it vs reported an exception: `XXXActivity has no public methods called onEvent`.

but in reality the activity had an `onEvent` method.

Can help me?

Here is my code!

```
[Activity(Label = "BaseActivity")]
public class BaseActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //EventBus.Default.Register(this);
        try
        { 
            JMessageClient.RegisterEventReceiver(this.Application.ApplicationContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" ==ex==" + ex.Message); 
        }
        // Create your application here
    }

public void onEventMainThread(CN.Jpush.IM.Android.Api.Event.MessageEvent Event)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" ==1==");
    }
...

}
```

IMRecActivity

```
[Activity(Label = "IMRecActivity")]
public class IMRecActivity : BaseActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Create your application here
    }

public void onEvent(CN.Jpush.IM.Android.Api.Event.MessageEvent Event)
    {
       // CN.Jpush.IM.Android.Api.Event.MessageEvent me = (MessageEvent)Event;
        CN.Jpush.IM.Android.Api.Model.Message msg = Event.Message;
        switch (msg.ContentType.ToString())
        {
            case "text":
       TextContent textContent = (TextContent)msg.Content;

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" ==JMessage OnEvent==" + textContent.Text);
                break;
            default:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" ==JMessage OnEvent==" + msg.Content);
                break;
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" ==JMessage OnEvent==");

    }
}
```

JMessageClient.RegisterEventReceiver(this.Application.ApplicationContext); this used to register an EventBus in the .JAR.With the code,you can see that I have declare onEvent method,but it not working.
By the way,I already uesed a tool like jd-gui to see how it work.
Here is the way to download the .JAR file:
https://www.jpush.cn/downloads/sdk/android/

The Official website,which is a Chinese website.
https://www.jpush.cn/common/products

Comment: you should post your code and error log

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend investigating the respective .jar using a tool like jd-gui(http://jd.benow.ca/) to see what the expected method visibility is. You can then use respective Metadata fixes to resolve any issues you find there after the generated binding is created.

I've created a generic guide to help out with this task in which you can look into:

https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

Comment: Thanks for you answer.But the url can't be visited,is it error?

Comment: @kingcaigen I can visit both those urls

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't know why ,I can't visit https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb,but I can visit https://github.com/JonDouglas

Comment: This is a public gist and should be available.

Comment: I think this is because I am in China